# android: reading table gives multiple copies of the same object

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In SecondActivity.java, I am trying to populate a SQLite table with the following data and later read rows based on the 3rd parameter(school/shopping/restaurant). When I debug the app, I am getting multiple copies of the same object.

```
 DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // Inserting default todos
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addtodo(new Todo(1,"Wallet", "SCHOOL"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(2,"Laptop", "SCHOOL"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(3,"Phone", "SCHOOL"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(4,"Laptop Charger", "SCHOOL"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(5,"Phone Charger", "SCHOOL"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(6,"USB", "SCHOOL"));


        db.addtodo(new Todo(8,"Wallet", "SHOPPING"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(9,"Phone", "SHOPPING"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(10,"Coupons", "SHOPPING"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(11,"Shopping List", "SHOPPING"));


        db.addtodo(new Todo(12,"Wallet", "RESTAURANT"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(13,"Phone", "RESTAURANT"));
        db.addtodo(new Todo(14,"Gift Cards", "RESTAURANT"));

        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        ArrayList<Todo> tags_school = db.getAllTodo("SCHOOL");
        ArrayList<Todo> tags_restaurant = db.getAllTodo("RESTAURANT");
        ArrayList<Todo> tags_shopping = db.getAllTodo("SHOPPING");

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<Todo>();

        switch (message){
            case "SCHOOL":{
                todolist = tags_school;
                break;
            }
            case "SHOPPING":{
                todolist = tags_shopping;
                break;
            }
            case "RESTAURANT":{
                todolist = tags_restaurant;
                break;
            }
            case "CUSTOM":{

                break;}
        }


        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        TodoAdapter adapter = new TodoAdapter(this, todolist);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

}
Here is the function to do so in my DatabaseHelper.java

```
public ArrayList<Todo> getAllTodo(String tag) {
        ArrayList<Todo> noteList = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NOTES + " WHERE " + KEY_TAG + "='"+tag+"';";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//I THINK THE QUERY IS GETTING MULTIPLE TIMES
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                Todo todo = new Todo();
                todo.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                todo.setNote(cursor.getString(1));
                todo.setTag(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                noteList.add(todo);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }

        // return contact list
        return noteList;
    }
```

These are the contents of tags_school.
[Here is the first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyI1p.png)
[Here is the 2nd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20Nd.png)
I am supposed to read only 6 objects but am reading 121. This number varies each time I run the code. Very confusing. I don't know where it's going wrong.

Comment: Running your app multiple times may be adding same entries in the db. Clear app data and check.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your complete code, I would recommend an easy fix for your problem with a different approach.

Like Altaf said, clean app's data from app manager on the device or emulator and run the app for first time to see how many records you get.

If problem still exists, check your code whether you insert data in onCreate/onResume as if its in onCreate/onResume then every time activity loads, data will be inserted without any action to insert data.

Add constraints like primary key, unique key etc on the database tables so if its unknowingly inserting data again the code will fail at that moment and you will have your culprit code which is inserting data again in database without any action to insert data.

It would be a good practice to add field timeCreated in the database table TABLE_NOTES and ToDo POJO which can either be a long or a String (formatted date using SimpleDateFormat with hour and minute when entries are added). Add Log.d statements which prints data insertion time and when you run the program again and again, it will be a debugging data which will help you identify if the data is inserted multiple times and when is it inserted.